# Transactional file manipulation in python

Tags: python, file, transactions

I constantly need to process large amounts of heavy CSV files in order to modify their content (transform some fields, enrich others with extra data, etc).  I went through a bunch of solutions already, all of them with ups and downs:

1. file system-based solutions are straightforward but messy, with files renamed with "-.wip" extensions etc, rather uggly and laborious to restore when something goes wrong
2. db-based solutions are cleaner but heavier and can be tiresome to deploy in our environment
3. whatever the solution, I always end up maintaining in-house solutions that are not really convincing.

Therefore I'm looking for a python-based solution allowing me to basically:

1. open an input file
2. process its input
3. write the processed input in an output file
4. all that in a transactional mode

"Transactional mode" guaranteeing that if anything goes wrong (something or someone trying to access the input or output file during processing, exception raising, eventually software or hardware crash), the transaction gets rolled back, meaning the input file remains untouched and the output file is erased.

Ideally, a file system-based solution would be the best, without any database in the way.
I already had a look at [acidfile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/acidfile/1.2.0) which is interesting but isn't exactly transactional.

Comment: (Please feel free to elaborate the -1/close...)

Comment: You can use a traditional serialization/deserialization processing using your filesystem with file locking, for instance using [LockFile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lockfile). I used that solution for JSON files. Or, you can use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) which is standard in Python…

Comment: I would also be interested in a general solution or best practice. My personal solution is usually to write the output to a new file, and never modify the input.